# Column count in a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to put `COUNT(item_id)` in this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `uid` = '3' AND `seen` = '0' AND id IN (
SELECT MAX(id), COUNT(item_id)
FROM `notifications`
GROUP BY item_id
)  ORDER BY id DESC
```

But This error occurred: **Operand should contain 1 column(s).**

**Table:**

```
[id] [uid] [item_id] [seen]
 1     3       69       0
 2     3       69       0
 3     3       70       0
 4     3       69       0
 5     3       70       0
 6     3       69       0
```

**Expected output:** (Order BY id DESC) where **69** is the last record.

```
[item_id] [num]
    69      4
    70      2
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  The error is pretty self explanatory -- you can't use multiple columns within the `in` clause.

Comment: The `IN (...)` subquery must return rows with one column each, not two.

Comment: Actually, MySQL does allow multi-column IN; but the left hand argument must be a tuple with the same number and type of items. `(a, b) IN (SELECT x, y FROM ...)` and `(a, b) IN ((a, c), (b, d), ....)` are both valid.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . Actually, you *can* use multiple columns with the `IN` clause.  That is something the OP is not doing and does not need, but MySQL does support tuples with `IN`.

Comment: what is the schema of your table and what is expected output? for now solution - `SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE uid = '3' AND seen = '0' AND id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM notifications GROUP BY item_id )  ORDER BY id DESC ;`

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct, I was referring more to this specific error.  I shouldn't have generalized the statement since `mysql` supports tuples.  Other databases do not.

Comment: @Vivek Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample data and expected results, there's no need for a subquery:

```
select item_id, count(*)
from notifications
group by item_id
where uid = 3 and seen = 0
order by max(id) desc;
```

- [Sample Demo](http://rextester.com/CSG53087)

Answer (score 1):

An educated guess says that you want a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT n.*, nmax.cnt
FROM notifications n JOIN
     (SELECT item_id,  MAX(id) as max_id, COUNT(item_id) as cnt
      FROM notifications
      GROUP BY item_id
     ) nmax
     ON n.item_id = nmax.item_id AND nmax.id = nmax.max_id
WHERE n.uid = 3 AND n.seen = 0  -- removed the single quotes because these are probably numbers
ORDER BY n.id DESC;
```

It is unclear whether you want the filtering conditions in the subquery as well.

Comment: Expected output has been added to the question.